# Change color and bullet of \itemize together

Tags: beamer, color, itemize

I want to create two new commands for new bullets in `\itemize`. A green `+` for `\pro` and a red `-` for `\con`, the text should be default black. I know how to change the symbols and the color alone, but how to combine both commands I don't know. At this point I just have:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{default}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}[ngerman]
\usepackage{booktabs}

% COMMANDS 
\newcommand{\pro}{\item[$+$]}
\newcommand{\con}{\item[$-$]}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Grundlagen}
\begin{itemize}
    \pro has to be green
    \con has to be red
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

It's probably very simple, but I haven't figured it out yet. Can someone tell me the full command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stick your desired colour inside of your `\pro`/`\con` definitions:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{default}

% PACKAGES
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}[ngerman]
\usepackage{booktabs}

% COMMANDS 
\newcommand<>{\pro}{\item#1[\color{green}$+$]}
\newcommand<>{\con}{\item#1[\color{red}$-$]}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Grundlagen}
\begin{itemize}
    \pro has to be green
    \con has to be red
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks very much!

Comment: @sp8cky You're welcome!